# BeautifulSoup: Getting empty variables

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get the value of some variables of a web page:

```
itemPage='https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/legislaturas/1' 
url = urlopen(itemPage)
soupItem=BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')
dataInicio=soupItem.find('dataInicio')
dataFim=soupItem.find('dataFim')
```

However, `dataInicio` and `dataFim` are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here. First, soup expects a string as input; check your `url` and see that it's actually `<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x036D7770>`. You can `read()` it, which produces a JSON byte string which is usable. But if you'd prefer to stick with XML parsing, I'd recommend using Python's `request` library to obtain a raw XML string (pass in correct headers to specify XML).

Secondly, when you create your soup object, you need to pass in `features="xml"` instead of `"lxml"`.

Putting it all together:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

item_page = "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/legislaturas/1"
response = requests.get(item_page, headers={"accept": "application/xml"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "xml")

data_inicio = soup.find("dataInicio")
data_fim = soup.find("dataFim")
print(data_inicio)
print(data_fim)
```

Output:

```
<dataInicio>1826-04-29</dataInicio>
<dataFim>1830-04-24</dataFim>
```

Comment: Nice answer, just a minor detail - BeautifulSoup accepts strings _and_ file-like objects. HTTPResponse is such an object and we can pass it to BeautifulSoup without reading it.

Comment: Sure, that seems accurate, but then OP's code should work by simply changing `"lxml"` to `"xml"` in the bs object, but it doesn't--curious why.

Comment: It does if you set the Accept header (we can set headers with `urllib.request.Request()`). It works with `"lxml"` too if you use lowercase, because `lxml` converts all tag names to lowercase. But it may be best not to set the Accept header; the API will return json and we can get the data with `response.json()['dados']['dataFim']`, without using Beautiful Soup.